# How to append text to multiple files in python?

Tags: python, text, append, permission-denied

There are multiple examples how one can append text to a SINGLE file.

What I would like to do is append the same text to ALL the files in the "folder1".

This is what I have tried so far.

```
import os

dir = (r'C:\Users\User1\Desktop\folder1')

for i in os.listdir(dir):
        file = open(dir, 'a')
        file.write("My desired text" + "\n")

file.close()
```

What I am getting right now is this error:

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
> 'C:\Users\arvydas\Desktop\nice_name'

I have:

- ran the script through cmd on windows as administrator
- made sure that the folder name is not the same as the names of the files
  -checked the folder permissions..

whats wrong?

Comment: Likely not your problem, but note that the `.close` call needs to be in the loop (or, alternatively, auto-closed using `with`. Currently, you code is only closing the last file.

Comment: You're opening `dir` which is a folder, so of course it fails.  Presumably you meant to open `i` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file directs to your folder, sure.
So if you use that path to create a folder

```
file = open(dir, 'a')
```

you are basically doing

```
file = open(r'C:\Users\User1\Desktop\folder1', 'a')
```

And obviously, that's not what you want. I see that you are iterating through the folders files though, with `i`. So why not use that?
Additionally, using plain `i` wont work. You have to combine that with your `dir`.

```
import os

dir = (r'/Users/aspera/Documents/Python/Py_Programs/tests/my_folder')

for i in os.listdir(dir):
        file = open(f"{dir}/{i}", 'a')
        file.write("My desired text" + "\n")

file.close()
```

Comment: Thank you, I have replaced dir with i as you advised.

Now the code runs with no errors, but desired text doesn't appear in the files.

Comment: It works!! There is no way I would have figured this (f"{dir}/{i}", 'a') line out tonight or anytime soon. I am too new in python, but I am very happy I can do useful things with it. This is magic. Thank you very much @BuddyBob for taking your time to help me out. Have a nice friday evening!